# Error reading xml files in ftp with XDocument.Parse

Tags: c#

I try to read xml in four ftp folder
Often (7 times on 10) i recive errors about xml files (like 'unexpected end of file has occured' etc) but files are 100% corrects.

I read xml to return list of orders headers in files.

Is WebClient best way?

```
private static async Task<List<Order>>GetOrdersFromFolder(List<string>filesList,string folder)
{
  var orders = new List<Order>();

        foreach (var file in filesList)
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
            if (extension == ".xml")
            {
                WebClient request = new WebClient(); 
                string url = "ftp://xxxxxxx/" + "myfiles/" + folder + "/" + file;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd");
                var stringData = await request.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stringData);
                IEnumerable<IEnumerable<XElement>> ordersList = GetXElement(doc);

                foreach (var order in ordersList)
                {
                    var order = new Order();
                    order.FullPath = url;

                    foreach (var field in order)
                    {
                        var name = (string)field.Attribute("name");
                        MapField(order, field, name);
                    }

                    orders.Add(order);
                }
            }
        }
        return orders;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that better to download all files first and parsing them one by one afterwards? Your code could fail as soon as you have parsing issues with 1st file.

Comment: you are right... but i would try to read without any save operations. Maybe i do as you suggest

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? What other exceptions are you getting aside 'Unexpected end of file'?

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(stringData);

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably these type error occurs just because the (XML) response dose not have a primary root element that means a parent node, the code mention below might be a clue to resolve the conflict.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string get_XML = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><Orders>" + 
            response.Trim() + "</Orders>";
            doc.Load(new StringReader(get_XML));
```

Comment: Every xml is correctly formatted and has a root <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>